# Experience editor missing Workflow

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor

When I edit the content on the content editor the workflow is triggering and showing Request for approval command option under the Review tab, whereas when I edit the content through Experience editor item version get increased but workflow status still as **No** why?.

Can you please help on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Vignesh Jothikumar

Comment: Is this "Request for approval" a custom command button?

Comment: Can you add some more details, how you created and set up the workflow?

Comment: Request for approval is a custom command button. I had followed up the below blog to just created a simple workflow

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFDUgiQCTmU&list=PLfRWjEN_vCUZqAk8ks5j36yM-BCWup-SZ&index=1